# Automation using Watir button elements

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, watir

So I have been experimenting with Watir automation scripts using Ruby. I have tried to experiment with different websites, like Twitter, Gmail, and Yahoo. Here is the catch: I am able to open a browser, login, and get to the home page. On all of these whether it is compose a new email or tweet every time I select it with the appropriate ID or Class, it throws an error in the terminal like this...

> .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:533:in `assert_element_found': unable to locate element, using {:title=>"compose", :tag_name=>"button"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
>       from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:505:in`assert_exists'
>       from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:114:in `click'
>       from yahoo_mail.rb:18:in`compose_email'
>       from yahoo_mail.rb:27:in `'

My question is, are there elements that you simply cannot click or select using Watir automation?

EDIT: How would I be able to hit this to be more specific? I seem to be getting the same results on Yahoo, Gmail, and Twitter when it comes to composing anything after getting logged in. So I how would I hit this button?

button id="global-new-tweet-button" type="button" class="js-global-new-tweet js-tooltip btn primary-btn tweet-btn js-dynamic-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-component-term="new_tweet_button">

Answer (score 0):

The HTML for the Compose button is basically the following (NOTE: id attribute removed):

```
<button tabindex="0" data-action="compose" title="Compose" class="btn btn-compose">
```

Your stacktrace indicates that you're using this locator:

```
{:title=>"compose", :tag_name=>"button"}
```

If you change `:title=>"compose"` to `:title=>"Compose"`, you should be in business.

Comment: I got really excited because I was hoping that would be the answer because that made alot of sense. However in this scenario it wasnt the case, here is the html that I am trying to hit...<button id="global-new-tweet-button" type="button" class="js-global-new-tweet js-tooltip btn primary-btn tweet-btn js-dynamic-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-component-term="new_tweet_button">

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following code?

`button(id:'global-new-tweet-button').when_present.click`

Maybe you were clicking the button without checking if it is already present on the page.